# Is it possible to use Glade with Scala?

Tags: scala, gtk, gtk3

In my hunt for various GUI frameworks, I remembered GTK being a fairly mature library for making user interfaces for desktop applications.

And it got me wondering, is it possible to use the Glade interface designer with Scala? Is there perhaps a Scala-optimised framework or library to make the process more painless?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there exists [a GTK+ binding for Java](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/), and from [an unofficial source](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Scala-gtk) it seems like you can use this in Scala.

This binding contains class [`Builder`](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/gtk/Builder.html) with method `addFromFile()`, so you should be able to create a UI file in Glade, save it, then load it in your Scala project, and use the method `getObject()` to access the objects defined in Glade.

For more details you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14307676/3488231) and its answers, which deal with Java, but should be very similar to Scala.

Answer (score 0):

As Scala is interoperable with Java, you can use it's bindings. I highly recommend you to first see [a scala REPL micro tutorial for Ubuntu](https://blogs.gnome.org/ssareen/2017/04/19/lets-get-functional-around-gtk/) then read and understand [what is GtkBuilder and how to create Gtk+ interfaces using Glade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade_Interface_Designer). Then a proposed process could be:

1. Create your apps UIs using Glade
2. Call GtkBuilder in your Scala code to interact with UI parts (send receive data)
3. Create Scala script file for each UI
4. Create a separate backend app with REST interface to present app input/ouput as UI state changes
5. Connect the two apps

By doing so, you'll get a set of bash scripts (written in Scala) each draw a native UI when executed. Whenever the backend is running, it's possible for UI to be used as I/O of backend app.